# Why is my System.out.println not working? Also this is not the main class and when i try to access it from the main class i don't get the output

Tags: java, getter

the code isn't giving the output

```
public class Init{

    private String clientName;
    private String clientNumber;
    private double balance;

    public Init(ASCIIDataFile file){

        clientNumber = file.readString();
        clientName = file.readString();
        balance = file.readDouble();
    } 




 public String getClientName(){
  System.out.println(clientName);  // `not working`  
    return clientName;  
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize your Init class? Maybe the `clientName` is empty and the `System.out.println(clientName)` prints just an empty line.

Comment: clientName is not empty because when i do a sysout for clientName inside the constructor, it gives me an output.

Comment: @kay Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score -2):

You are missing `this.` in constructor therefore `clientName` in `getClientName()` is empty

Your constructor should be like this:

```
    public Init(ASCIIDataFile file){

        this.clientNumber = file.readString();
        this.clientName = file.readString();
        this.balance = file.readDouble();
    }
```

Comment: `this` keyword isn't required in the constructor. It's good practice to have it, but it not required.

Comment: When you don't use ```this.``` keyword in this case data are not stored in class variables but in local variables in constructor. Therefore when calling ```getClientName()``` clientName is ```null```

Comment: You're wrong.```public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human human = new Human("S");
        human.getName();
    }
}

class Human {
    private String name;

    public Human(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        System.out.println(name);
        return name;
    }
}``` and it prints the name.

Comment: I think that you're blind. His parameter name is `clientName` and his constructor parameter name is `file`. Check how I named it, it's the same.

Comment: Yup, I am blind. My mistake